# ExecuteStoreCommand "Delete" returning different record count to "DeleteObject" post delete, why?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Got a strange one here. I am using EF 6 over SQL Server 2012 and C#.

If I delete a record, using DeleteObject, I get:

```
        //order.orderitem count = 11

        db.OrderItem.DeleteObject(orderitem);  
        db.SaveChanges();

        var order = db.order.First(r => r.Id == order.id);

        //Order.OrderItem count = 10, CORRECT
```

If I delete an Order Item, using ExecuteStoreCmd inline DML, I get:

```
        //order.orderitem count = 11

        db.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM ORDERITEM WHERE ID ={0}", orderitem.Id);

        var order = db.Order.First(r => r.Id == order.id);

        //order.orderitem count = 11, INCORRECT, should be 10
```

So the ExecuteStoreCommand version reports 11, however the OrderItem is definitely deleted from the DB, so it should report 10. Also I would have thought First() does an Eager search thus repopulating the "order.orderitem" collection.

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks.

EDIT: I am using ObjectContext

EDIT2: This is the closest working solution I have using "detach". Interestingly the "detach" actually takes about 2 secs ! Not sure what it is doing, but it works.

```
db.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM ORDERITEM WHERE ID ={0}", orderitem.Id);
db.detach(orderitem);
```

It would be quicker to requery and repopulate the dataset. How can I force a requery? I thought the following would do it:

```
 var order = db.order.First(r => r.Id == order.id);
```

EDIT3: This seems to work to force a refresh post delete, but still take about 2 secs:

```
db.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins,Order.OrderItem);
```

I am still not really understanding why one cannot just requery as a Order.First(r=>r.id==id) type query oftens take much less than 2 secs.

Comment: "I am still not really understanding why one cannot just requery as a Order.First(r=>r.id==id) type query oftens take much less than 2 secs."   This is why dbContexts and their entities should be short-lived. The more possible entities the DbContext has cached, the more entities it has to programatically review for possible references to an entity you want to remove/alter. With a fresh DbContext, removing a child is fast, and any other possible FK conflicts would be resolved by the DB with FK violations when you attempt to save. (Hence the recommended approach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would likely be because the Order and it's order items are already known to the context when you perform the ExecuteStoredCommand. EF doesn't know that the command relates to any cached copy of Order, so the command will be sent to the database, but not update any loaded entity state. WHere-as the first one would look for any loaded OrderItem, and when told to remove it from the DbSet, it would look for any loaded entities that reference that order item.

If you don't want to ensure the entity(ies) are loaded prior to deleting, then you will need to check if any are loaded and refresh or detach their associated references.

If orderitem represents an entity should just be able to use:

```
db.OrderItems.Remove(orderitem);
```

If the order is loaded, the order item should be removed automatically. If the order isn't loaded, no loss, it will be loaded from the database when requested later on and load the set of order items from the DB.

However, if you want to use the SQL execute approach, detaching any local instance should remove it from the local cache.

```
db.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM ORDERITEM WHERE ID ={0}", orderitem.Id);
var existingOrderItem = db.OrderItems.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == orderItem.Id);
if(existingOrderItem != null)
    db.Entity(existingOrderItem).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

I don't believe you will need to check for the orderItem's Order to refresh anything beyond this, but I'm not 100% sure on that. Generally though when it comes to modifying data state I opt to load the applicable top-level entity and remove it's child.

So if I had a command to remove an order item from an order:

```
public void RemoveOrderItem(int orderId, int orderItemId)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        // TODO: Validate that the current user session has access to this order ID
        var order = context.Orders.Include(x => x.OrderItems).Single(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
        var orderItem = order.OrderItems.SingleOrDefault(x => x.OrderItemId == orderItemId);
        if (orderItem != null)
            order.OrderItems.Remove(orderItem);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The key points to this approach.

- While it does mean loading the data state again for the operation, this load is by ID so it's fast.
- We can/should validate that the data requested is applicable for the user. Any command for an order they should not access should be logged and the session ended.
- We know we will be dealing with the current data state, not basing decisions on values/data from the point in time that data was first read.

Comment: Huge thanks for this. I am using ObjectContext and I cannot see "Local" and "Entity" as properties. As I understand it DBContext is a wrapper around ObjectContext. How I achieve the same with ObjectContext especially around "detaching"?

Comment: The closest I have got to a solution is EDIT2 in my question. However this addition does take 2 secs